# Octokit.js github base url setup

Tags: node.js, github-api-v3, octokit-js

I am trying to authenticate with my enterprise github through `App` in `octokit.js` but I couldn't find any parameter to change gihub url. Can someone please help?

```js
const {Octokit, App} = require('octokit')

// below points to github.com
const app = new App({ appId: appId1, privateKey: privateKey1 }) 

// below does not work
//const app = new App({ appId: appId1, privateKey: privateKey1 , baseUrl: mygitHub })

app.octokit.rest.apps.getAuthenticated();
```

Using nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer at https://github.com/octokit/app.js/#constructor

```js
const { Octokit } = require("@octokit/core");
new App({
  appId: 123,
  privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...",
  oauth: {
    clientId: 123,
    clientSecret: "secret",
  },
  webhooks: {
    secret: "secret",
  },
  Octokit: Octokit.defaults({
    baseUrl: "https://ghe.my-company.com/api/v3",
  }),
});
```